# Update .xlsm file values python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a .xlsm file as a reference template. I want to update the values of this .xlsm file using python from a .csv file.

template .xlsm ----> Update values using .csv

What has not worked : 
I tried using pandas.to_excel method. but the .xlsm file gets corrupted after I write to sheet.

Could someone please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2):

openpyxl supports `xlsm` file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
update(wb2, csvfile.csv) # this is where you need to work according to your need.
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
wb.close()
```

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks, would give it a try

Comment: The code is badly written, and it won't work even if it is changed. Since the `wb2.save('test.xlsm')` will save it as a plain xls, without any xlsm functionalities.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.

Comment: Actually this worked for me, and the file was saved successfully, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to try `xlwings`, using it something like this?

```
def update(workbook, csv_file):
    ws = workbook.sheets[2]
    ws.range('B14').value = 155

from xlwings import Book
wb = Book(r'test.xlsm')
update(wb, csv_file)
wb.save('test1.xlsm')
wb.close()
```

This is the best tool to update xlsm files since it uses WindowsAPI and macros are triggered in case something is changed. This means, it won't work on Linux.

Of course, `update` function must do something more meaningful than changing the B14 cell in the 3rd sheet.

For more info, please read http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html